# Whats going on here global[{a}]=7

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code.

```
a=7
global[{a}]=7
global[{a}] // returns 7

b[{a}]=7
b[{a}] // returns undefined
```

I honestly have no idea whats going on, it seems like an object with an object as a property, but then i dont see why the second example is undefined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this ? what is global ? is it an object or something.. Is it declared somewhere ?

Comment: sure, `global` is the same as `window` when running in the brower. its an object. the global one.

Comment: What is `b`? `b[{a}]` throws a ReferenceError since it's not declared

Comment: `global` does not exists in edge.

Comment: @NinaScholz This is in a Node environment.

Comment: I can't reproduce the second result... when `b` is defined.

Comment: i was in repl mode. for clarification, i should have said that since its relevant (to be fair i didnt know it was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what I guess is happening.

As you mentioned earlier, global is same as `window` object.

So, when you are doing,

`global[{a}] = 7;`

It's similar to `global["[object Object]"] = 7`

Then you will get the answer :: `global[{}]` as `7`.

Now , for this

```
b[{a}]=7
b[{a}] // returns undefined
```

You haven't declared `b` as object that's why you are getting answer as undefined.

If you do the following, result would be same;

```
b = {};
b[{a}]=7;
b[{a}] // returns 7
```

Comment: YES!!!! now `b["[object Object]"]` is 7 as apposed to undefined!! genious.

Comment: if you don't define `b` and try to access some property on it, you'll get an error not `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

When you access something using bracket notation, whatever you put into brackets is converted to string.
Any object after conversion to string returns `[object Object]`

When you do `global[{a}]` it is converted to `global["[object Object]"]` and stored/accessed on that property name

```js
a = 7
b = {}

b[{a}] = 7
console.log(b[{ a }]) // returns 7
console.log(b["[object Object]"]) // returns 7
```

Comment: so shouldnt `b["[object Object]"]` be 7? ..thanks so much for explaining what was going on there, still confused a bit about <--

Comment: must be because im in repl mode. i get undefined :( thanks for explaining what was going on tho